# base64 image file in array is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

I tried to load the base64 image string into array by `<input type="file"/>`
I am sure the string is in the array but when I call the array element the console callback is undefined.

as following my code:

```
fileChange(event){
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            let imageFiles = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {

              let reader = new FileReader();
              reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
              reader.onload = (e) => {
                  imageFiles[i] = e.target.result;
                  console.log(e.target.result);
              };
            }
            console.log(imageFiles);
            console.log(imageFiles[0]);
        }
  }

//console result:
//"base64 string"
//[]-> 0: "base64 string"
//undefined
```

I think it because the base64 string is too long, but I have no idea to solve the problem.

It's some ways to solve it?

Comment: Use `imageFiles[imageFiles.length]` instead of `imageFiles[i]` as `i` is not not going to be captured. Your `console.log(imageFiles[0]);` may occur before `onload()` executes so its value has not been set.

Comment: If you move those last two console.logs into your `reader.onload` callback, you will probably get a result — reading files is asynchronous, so `console.log(imageFiles)` is currently getting called before the files have finished loading into the variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Why do you need base64? using [URL.createObjectURL](https://www.google.se/search?q=URL.createObjectURL+mdn&oq=URL.createObjectURL+mdn&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.2603j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is better if you are going to display them and having blob/files is better for uploading. Object url is also synchronous and faster

Comment: Yes, I find the problem, I console the file in the `reader.onload` function

Comment: @Endless I want to preview all the select image file in my page

Comment: @ChamperWu then use objectURL's

Comment: @Endless Im reading the doc now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two statements

```
console.log(imageFiles);
console.log(imageFiles[0]);
```

are called immediately, when `reader.onload` is not completed yet. Hence, the `imageFiles` array is empty.

You need to wait until the image is loaded to be able to log it. One way is to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Here is an example of loading multiple files. `Promise.all` will wait until all files are loaded and then log them.

```js
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", fileChange);
function fileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        console.clear();
        console.log("Loading selected files...");
        let promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
            promises[i] = new Promise(resolve => {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    resolve(e.target.result);
                };
            });
        }      
        Promise.all(promises).then(console.log);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple"/>
```